# Re-prompt user after invalid input in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I'm writing this program in java where I need to re-prompt the user after an invalid input. I came to a solution only to discover that if the user enters another invalid input after the re-prompt then it continues. Can someone please show me a better solution to this? I'll show you what I had anyway:

```
System.out.println("What is your age?\n");
    age = userInput.nextInt();

    if((age > 120) || (age < 1)) {//error message
        System.out.println("ERROR Please enter a valid age");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("What is your age?\n");
        age = userInput.nextInt();
    }//end if
```

if the user entered an invalid input after they were prompted again, the program would just continue, how can I overcome this?

Comment: You need some kind of loop, e.g. a do-while loop. I think you already guessed that, looking at your tags...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `if` with `while`.

BAM, problem solved.

Comment: The while loop worked can't believe I didn't think of that how embarrassing, thanks everyone

Comment: @MattBryant You're welcome to offer a non-nasty solution that does not duplicate code.
EDIT: is a while(true) with a break really less nasty in your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `while` loop.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("What is your age?\n");
    age = userInput.nextInt();
    if ((age > 120) || (age < 1))
        System.out.println("ERROR Please enter a valid age\n");
    else
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use do-while:

```
boolean valid;
do {
     System.out.println("What is your age?\n");
     age = userInput.nextInt();
     valid = age > 1 && age < 120;
     if (!valid) {
       System.out.println("ERROR Please enter a valid age");
     }
}while (!valid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in to a while loop so that it keeps looping until the conditions are met --

```
System.out.println("What is your age?\n");
age = userInput.nextInt();

while((age > 120) || (age < 1)) {//error message
    System.out.println("ERROR Please enter a valid age");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("What is your age?\n");
    age = userInput.nextInt();
}//end if
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this

---->One time check - is your input is empty or just pressed the spacebar

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);      
System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
String input = scnr.nextLine(); 

boolean isEmpty = input == null || input.trim().length() == 0;
if (isEmpty){
    System.out.println("Enter a string again: ");
    input = scnr.nextLine(); 
}
```

------> Multiple time check- is your input is empty or just pressed the spacebar

```
 Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);       
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    input = scnr.nextLine();
}
     while (input == null || input.trim().length() == 0);
```

**Important:** 
Don't forget that input should be static string in this case.

```
static String input="";
```

Answer (score 0):

// Using do-while loop, this problem can be tackled.

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a pin: ");
        pin = sc.nextInt();
    } while (pin != 12345);
    System.out.println("Welcome to program");
```

Comment: One minor nit. PINs shouldn't be considered as ints. Since `0123` is a valid PIN, but the `0` would be truncated as an int.

Comment: I did not get your point, can you please explain in detail because I am beginner.

Comment: No problem. PIN, postal codes, and telephone numbers should be treated as strings and never as an integer. This is because, when you parse a number, leading zeros are removed. e.g., `0123` would be parsed as `123`. The same problem occurs with ZIP codes in the US -- ZIP codes are 5-digits and get bigger as you go from North to South and East to West. In the northeast they start with `0`. So, `02010` would parse as `2010` which isn't a valid ZIP code.  Hopefully, that makes sense.

Comment: Try entering some string and see what happens :)