# Converting pseudo-code while loop in to java

Tags: java, while-loop, pseudocode

I am trying to convert a pseudo-code written to java, i have come across a while loop that i am able to understand
 In the given pseudo-code  i am unable to comprehend what both the while loops denote, especially what **to** key word means.

Does it mean that i need to run the while loop until i is less than a and b variables? I checked all throughout the internet and i was unable to find any pseudo-code example that used such a while loop

```
 read a;
    read b;
    i=0
    if a>b
    while(to i<a)
    print(i)
    i++;
    end while
    else
    while(to i<b)
    print(i)
    i++;
    end while
    end if;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I see it, Line by Line:

**read a;**

Get an Integer value from User and place it into a declared **int** type variable named `a`. Use the **Scanner** class with **System.in** to do this. Be sure to let the User know what is going on and what is expected by way of a prompt. Also, validate the input to ensure a proper integer value is supplied and that the application will not fall into an exception.

**Hint:** Read up on the [Scanner#nextInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm) method and [Prompting in **while** loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721944/4725875).

---

**read b;**

Get an Integer value from User and place it into a declared **int** type variable named `b`. Use the **same** **Scanner** class with **System.in** to do this. Be sure to let the User know what is going on and what is expected by way of a prompt. Also, validate the input to ensure a proper integer value is supplied and that the application will not fall into an exception.

**Hint:** Read up on the [Scanner#nextInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm) method and [Prompting in **while** loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721944/4725875).

---

**i=0**

Declare a integer counter variable named `i` and initialize it to **0**.

---

**if a>b**

Create an **if** statement code block with `(a > b)` as its' condition. Yes, be sure your **if** statement code block has the opening and closing curly braces and your condition is properly enclosed in parentheses.

---

**while(to i<a)**

Within the `(a > b)` **if** statement code block (within the curly braces) start a **while** loop with the condition of `(i < a)`. This loop is to continue iterating until `i` gets **to** `a` which at that point the looping ends and any code below the loop can continue to run. Make sure your **while** loop contains a code block denoted by way of curly braces and make sure your **while** loop condition is properly enclosed within parentheses.

---

**print(i)**

Within the **while** loop code block (within its' curly braces) write the current integer value of counter `i` to the Console Window. You can use `System.out.println(i);` or you can use `System.out.print(i + " ");` to do this. The latter doesn't make the Console Window scroll so much while it prints all the values of `i` until it reaches one less than the value of `a`.

---

**i++;**

Add this **actual** code line *directly below* the code you used for printing to Console Window within the same **while** loop code block. This code line increments the counter variable `i` by **1**. It is the very same as writing: `i = i + 1;` but shorter. So, upon the next iteration of the **while** loop `i` will be one more than before when printed to the Console Window. This continues until `i` is one less that the value of `a` which was supplied by the User (remember).

---

**end while**

If you properly created your **while** loop code block earlier with open and closing curly braces, then you can basically ignore this line. It is simply the closing curly brace ( **}** ) for the **while** loop code block.

---

**else**

*Directly* below the `(a > b)` **if** statement's code block (after its' closing curly brace) add an **else** statement and code block (open and closing curly braces). If the code is to run within this block then the condition within the **if** statement above was false, `a` must be less than `b` instead of greater then `b`. There is no condition for an **else** statement.

---

**while(to i<b)**

Within the **else** statement code block (within the curly braces) start a **while** loop with the condition of `(i < b)`. This loop is to continue iterating until `i` gets **to** `b` which at that point the looping ends and any code below the loop can continue to run. Make sure your **while** loop contains a code block denoted by way of curly braces and make sure your **while** loop condition is properly enclosed within parentheses.

---

**print(i)**

Within this next **while** loop code block (within its' curly braces) write the current integer value of counter `i` to the Console Window. You can use `System.out.println(i);` or you can use `System.out.print(i + " ");` to do this. The latter doesn't make the Console Window scroll so much while it prints all the values of `i` until it reaches one less than the value of `b`.

---

**i++;**

Add this **actual** code line *directly below* the code you used for printing to Console Window within the same **while** loop code block. This code line increments the counter variable `i` by **1**. It is the very same as writing: `i = i + 1;` but shorter. So, upon the next iteration of this second **while** loop `i` will be one more than before when printed to the Console Window. This continues until `i` is one less that the value of `b` which was the second value supplied by the User (remember).

---

**end while**

If you properly created your second **while** loop code block earlier with open and closing curly braces within the **else** statement code block, then you can basically ignore this line. It is simply the closing curly brace ( **}** ) for the **while** loop code block.

---

**end if;**

If you properly created your code block for the **else** statement earlier with open and closing curly braces then you can basically ignore this line. It is simply the closing curly brace ( **}** ) for the **else** statement code block. If there was no **else** statement then it would simply be the closing brace ( **}** ) for the **if** statement.

---

You should hopefully have no problem writing this code now.